# I run into a discord.gateway warning "Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than x seconds."

Tags: python, discord.py

my simple bot checks of it got a .json file from an API, if it did, then the bot outputs some info and then deletes that .json file. But if it did not, then it checks again until there is a .json file in that directory.

Bot actually works fine, but I get a warning `Discord.gateway warning "Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than x seconds."`

Can it crush my bot? Because the bot is supposed to be constantly running.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

import json

import time

from config import TOKEN

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.AutoShardedBot(shard_count=2, command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')

@bot.command()
async def example(ctx):
    while True:
        try:
            f = open("result.json", "r")
            result = json.load(f)
            await ctx.send(f"some message, {result['name']}")
            os.remove("/home/user/Projects/project_folder/result.json")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            continue
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message?

Comment: @ImBadAtMath ofc, didn't find what would be helpful in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by putting `async.wait(0)` after `try:` and after `except:`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).